# How can I force JRuby to initialize a java ArrayList with java Longs instead of Fixnums?

Tags: ruby, jruby, jruby-java-interop

Someone on my team is writing a ruby/cucumber test that calls a java api that takes a `List<Long>` argument.  I'm trying to help him out but my jruby knowledge is pretty limited.  Whenever the call to the java method that takes `List<Long>` is made the java method is throwing some sort of class cast exception because the ArrayList contains all ruby `Fixnum` objects.

The following simplified code shows that I always get a Fixnum not a Java::JavaLang::Long

```
irb(main):017:0> java.util.ArrayList.new([12.to_java])[0].class
=> Fixnum
```

This is even though the following shows that 12.to_java produces a Long

```
irb(main):018:0> 12.class
=> Fixnum
irb(main):019:0> 12.to_java.class
=> Java::JavaLang::Long
```

I've also tried not using the constructor args

```
irb(main):020:0> a = java.util.ArrayList.new
=> #<Java::JavaUtil::ArrayList:0x314e60d2>
irb(main):021:0> a.add(12.to_java)
=> true
irb(main):022:0> a[0].class
=> Fixnum
```

And gone as far a just instantiating a java.lang.Long directly

```
irb(main):023:0> a = java.util.ArrayList.new
=> #<Java::JavaUtil::ArrayList:0xfdcb343>
irb(main):024:0> a.add(java.lang.Long.new(12))
=> true
irb(main):025:0> a[0].class
=> Fixnum
```

And my last attempt

```
irb(main):026:0> b = 12.to_java
=> #<Java::JavaLang::Long:0x244ff48e>
irb(main):027:0> b.class
=> Java::JavaLang::Long
irb(main):028:0> a = java.util.ArrayList.new
=> #<Java::JavaUtil::ArrayList:0x6a36ebaa>
irb(main):029:0> a.add b
=> true
irb(main):030:0> a.get(0).class
=> Fixnum
```

Comment: The above issue was a rabbit hole and not the real problem (as I suspected).  I've selected the more detailed answer below.  I still don't know why `12.to_java` produces a `Java::JavaLang:Long` but when that gets put in a java `List` it is converted back to a `Fixnum`.  But that was definitely not the issue as shown by @kares

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually, this is far easier than you think and will work fine if you just pass a `[]` around :)

while on the Ruby side JRuby makes sure values are Ruby-like but when it reaches the Java end - in case of a RubyArray instance passed to Java (which actually implements `java.util.List`) - it will auto-convert "toJava" at it's best. means for Ruby Fixnums you will get `java.lang.Long` on operations such as `java.util.List#get` :

```
public class JavaAPI {
    public void testListArgument(final List<Long> list) {
        System.out.println("list = " + list + " list.class = " + list.getClass() + " list[0].class = " + list.get(0).getClass());
    }
}
```

compile this .java (under *target/classes*) than doing something like `jruby -S irb` :

```
jruby-1.7.16 :007 > $CLASSPATH << 'target/classes'
 => ["file:/opt/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.16/lib/ruby/shared/readline/jline-2.11.jar", "file:/opt/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.16/lib/ruby/shared/readline/readline.jar", "file:target/classes/"] 
jruby-1.7.16 :009 > Java::JavaAPI.new.testListArgument [1]
list = [1] list.class = class org.jruby.RubyArray list[0].class = class java.lang.Long
 => nil
```